# PHP - Unable to find the socket transport "ssl"

Tags: php, ssl, pear

## System Info

- Win 10 Pro x64
- PHP 7.3.10 x64 TS
- HTTPD 2.4.34

I've followed this guide to generate the necessary key and certificate files.

[How do I allow HTTPS for Apache on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost#answer-55247967)

### httpd.conf

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

### extra/vhosts.conf

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "${CONF_PATH}/certs/localhost.cert"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "${CONF_PATH}/certs/localhost.key"

        ...
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

### php.ini

```
extension=openssl

[curl]
curl.cainfo="C:\bin\httpd\conf\certs\localhost.cert"

[openssl]
openssl.cafile="C:\bin\httpd\conf\certs\localhost.cert"
```

This is usually where people will say to copy `libeay32` and `ssleay32` but, just to document this for anyone else, these are no longer the files included with recent builds. They are `libcrypto` and `libssh` now. I copied those into the Apache bin directory.

Going to a page with `phpinfo()` confirms these settings, with SSL marked as enabled.

Let's do some HTTPS requests.

```
pecl update-channels
Updating channel "doc.php.net"
Channel "doc.php.net" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.php.net"
Channel "pear.php.net" is not responding over http://, failed with message: Connection to `ssl://pear.php.net:443' failed: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
Trying channel "pear.php.net" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pear.php.net" (Connection to `ssl://pear.php.net:443' failed: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is up to date
```

Well, that's no good. I saw some suggestions about removing an `-n` flag from the PECL script. So I did that. Let's see if it's any different now.

```
pecl update-channels
Updating channel "doc.php.net"
Channel "doc.php.net" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.php.net"
Channel "pear.php.net" is not responding over http://, failed with message: Connection to `ssl://pear.php.net:443' failed:
Trying channel "pear.php.net" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pear.php.net" (Connection to `ssl://pear.php.net:443' failed: )
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is up to date
```

No, that's actually worse. Now there's just less detail about why it's failing.

Anyone have any extra insight I'm missing here on why I'm not having any success?

Comment: Have you enabled `php_openssl` in your `php.ini`?

Comment: There should be a line like `extension=php_openssl.dll` that you can uncomment and use. If not, simply add the line and restart the server to see if it works.

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14191542/372172) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571090/372172).

Comment: Yes, it's enabled. I already said that. I made this question because that is the only answer anyone ever has and it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Your HTTPD php.ini (which you have checked with "Going to a page with phpinfo()") might be a different file than your `pecl` (command line) php.ini. Make sure that `pecl` is using a php.ini with openssl enabled. See `pecl config-show`, also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49623714/68939 .

Comment: It wasn't set, so I manually set it using `pecl config-set php_ini "C:\bin\php\%PHP_VERSION%\php.ini"` but the result is the same.

Comment: @DissidentRage, I am in exactly the same position as you. Hittin the exact same wall. I am just about to give up.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it to work by editing pecl.bat. Before it had this:

```
"%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%" -C -n -d date.timezone=UTC -d output_buffering=1 -d safe_mode=0 -d "include_path='%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%'" -d register_argc_argv="On" -d variables_order=EGPCS -f "%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%\peclcmd.php" -- %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

I changed it to:

```
"%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%" -c "%PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR%\php.ini" -C -n -d date.timezone=UTC -d output_buffering=1 -d safe_mode=0 -d "include_path='%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%'" -d register_argc_argv="On" -d variables_order=EGPCS -f "%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%\peclcmd.php" -- %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

In other words, I added this part:

```
-c "%PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR%\php.ini"
```

It's the same advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842400/ssl-issue-after-pear-channel-update-pear-php-net/49623714#49623714).

**UPDATE**

After this I got a new error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use result of built-in function in write context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Archive\Tar.php on line 639
```

So I went and edited Tar.php and changed this:

```
$v_att_list = & func_get_args();
```

To this:

```
$v_att_list = func_get_args();
```

Seems to have gotten me further, but now I get:

```
ERROR: The DSP mailparse.dsp does not exist.
```

The search continues....

Comment: Just adding this `-c "%PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR%\php.ini"` line worked for me! Thanks you!